# Can't open a url when using selenium under firefox

Tags: python, selenium

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [selenium webdriver.get(url) does not open the url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7347494/selenium-webdriver-geturl-does-not-open-the-url)

I'm using selenium python client and my code is quite simple :

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("http://www.google.com")
```

My firefox : 15.0.1
OS: Ubuntu
Python : 2.6.5

It does open the firefox but then it didn't open google, just stay there do nothing.

Any help ?

Comment: What version of Python & the python-bindings for Selenium are you using? It works for me with Python 2.7.2 & Selenium 2.25.0.

Comment: @MatthewTrevor I use selenium 2.25.0. this code runs ok on my mac, but have problem on ubuntu.

Comment: Does this answer from the other question help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/10597671/11265

Comment: @MatthewTrevor Not help.

Comment: You're going to have to provide more feedback. Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: Yes, i'm behind a proxy.

Comment: heh. I've come across with the similar problem on 14.0 ffox. So I've resolved it by rollback ffox to 12.0 ver. Have you tried to use previous ffox versions?