# How Can I Use Proxies For Selenium Python Firefox?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, firefox, proxy, selenium-firefoxdriver

I want to use a proxy for selenium python using the firefox webdriver. I can assign firefox a proxy through the normal browser's GUI but I don't know how to do it Selenium Python. It uses port 8080 and it does not need authentication.

Comment: This  question is already answered [look at this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18719980/proxy-selenium-python-firefox/31086235)

Comment: @ufopilot that does not work my ip is still the same and none of the settings changed

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.