# web application back button not getting click with selenium

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, click

win 7 32 bit with selenium 2.39

same piece of javacode for selenium working fine and completes off the test script in latest version of chrome (v31) and IE 10, however not with firefox 26.

### import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;

```
selenium.click("name=submit");
selenium.waitForPageToLoad("60000"); 
assertTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("ENQUIRY ERROR"));
takeScreenshot("screenshot.png", "screenshot.png");
selenium.click("name=menu");// hangs here this back, suppose to click the back button
selenium.waitForPageToLoad("60000");
takeScreenshot("menu.png", "menuback");
```

pls assist anyone, it looks like genuine issue, not sure if firefox require a fix or the selenium team or is there any tweak can be done in meantime.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, did you verifued that the element you tried to click is present?

```
assert backButton .isDisplayed();
```

Regarding the clicking, here is number of different approaches.

Finding the WebElement by the name argument:

```
WebElement backButton = driver.findElement(By.name("menu"));
backButton .click();
```

Or to write them together ("should" be the same):

```
driver.findElement(By.name("menu")).click();
```

Or you can use keyboard enter:

```
driver.findElement(By.name("menu")).sendKeys(Keys.Return);
```

Or:

```
driver.findElement(By.name("menu")).sendKeys(Keys.Enter);
```

Comment: tried all yet button not clicked, rather getting this in log:

Comment: "Could not convert screenshot to base64 - Error: Invalid base64 data: data"

Comment: fyi im running the job from my laptop connecting to test pc via teamviewer. test pc on 32 bit, my laptop on 64-bit pc. believe this is not an issue as chrome, ie able to run the test succesfully.

Comment: any expert able assist? or did any1 experience same issue? im still facing the issue, I tried on another website application with same domain name. fine with latest Internet explorer (version 11), chrome (version 31) but test stop for firefox version 26.

Pls assist.

Comment: this looks like genuine issue, not sure if its firefox bug or selenium driver bug. i can't reveal the website to simulate the issue as the website yet to be release to public and require login.

Comment: the test script contain 44 screenshot, could it be due to any restriction/limitation by selenium firefox webdriver?

Comment: If i understand correctly the data you provided, the error "Could not convert screenshot to base64" relates to the screenshot mechanism thats initialized (probably) after the error while trying to click on button happens.
Please tell me, doest the button found by driver.findElement(By.name("menu"))? is he displayed .isDisplayed()? do you got the button in some iframe?

Comment: hi stas,i will check if the button is found when the page is displayed. regarding the iframe, IE and Chrome run the script perfectly fine. pls assist further, i can provide details

Comment: i guess the button not found by  driver.findElement(By.name("menu")), isDisplayed() followed by system.out.print prints nothing. but the button is visible. pls assist

Comment: any real expert who can provide solution? anyone up for challenge?

Comment: I still didnt understand from your answer:
1. In what line exactly the failure happens- in the first screenshot?
2. If no- "i guess the button not found by driver.findElement(By.name("menu")), isDisplayed() followed by system.out.print prints nothing. but the button is visible" so, isDisplayed() on the button you need to click, returns true or false?

Comment: the last captured screenshot frm the test result is the screenshot before this line -> selenium.click("name=menu");// hangs here this back, supposed to click the back button. during test run, i can the test proceed right up to the page with back button (name=menu), but fail to do click and test run abruptly.

Comment: it didnt print anything, so it's false.

Comment: reproduce the problem and selenium team acknowledge firefox sees the element in div as invisible.

"FirefoxDriver thinks that element div#contents is not visible."

not sure if it require fix from firefox or selenium team...

Comment: Can you please post the relevant DOM part?

Comment: check the link inspection of the object via firebug                   http://imgur.com/VFHWhWs  seems like firebug inspection on dom showing nothing. seleniium team still investigating. looks like its firefox webdriver bug or selenium driver bug. manually navigating on firefox browser, we can click on tht button.

Comment: is there any workaround or anything that i can ask the developer to do to make the element visible (problem only seems with firefox webdriver though)

Comment: any expert can suggest any temporary work around? i tried driver.navigate().back() and still the test run abruptly same like the earlier problem..

Comment: Please find this bug description. Is that relevant to your situation?
http://grokbase.com/t/gg/selenium-developer-activity/13ctrttav3/issue-6774-in-selenium-click-does-not-work-in-webdriver-2-39-firefox-26

Comment: could be..selenium still investigating my issue which seems genuine..but i hope some temp work around is there..wonder why back click n navigation too doesnt work..

Comment: its not only with firefox 26, i tried few firefox version n same issue

Comment: any workaround? driver.get url seems failing, driver.get url works fine in IE n chrome though..

Comment: Are you working behind Proxy? I investigated more about this issue... looks like this issue appear for other users as well. 
Please check those links: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=2560 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7347494/selenium-webdriver-geturl-does-not-open-the-url

Comment: nope dont think so, other browser (IE and Chrome) running fine the script. hope selenium admit there's some serious bug interacting with firefox

Comment: Have you checked the two links in previous comment?

Comment: yup did check, tried the proxy setting and yet facing the same issue,im actually getting error "Could not convert screenshot to base64 - Error: Invalid base64 data: data" , which i highlighted above in the thread.

Comment: anyone facing similar issues, i can lot of comments on users facing similar issues..

Comment: if i comment out the takeScreenshot from the codes, the script running fine. some really serious fishy issue with takescreenshot with selenium with firefox integration.

Comment: how the takeScreenshot implemented? can you edit and add it in the question?

Comment: If i understant correctly, TakesScreenshot library not have takeScreenshot method (in Java): http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-api/2.11.0/org/openqa/selenium/TakesScreenshot.java it's something you got implemented locally in your project. Please provide your implementation of the method.

Comment: i've made my code more robust and it's perfectly fine in latest chrome version and IE. Only firefox the script hang, not performing button click. sure tht nothing wrong with my code. hope selenium release new version (2.40) asap. selenium aknowledge mentioning its firefox issue. hope solution will b there soon. any1 have any luck/workaround?

Comment: tried with new release selenium 2.40..getting this error "cannot find symbol.selenium = new WebDriverBackedSelenium". any idea y n any solution?

Comment: selenium webdriver code even with 2.40 jar not able to interact well with firefox. tried right up from ff23-27, button click FirefoxDriver thinks that element div#contents is not visible. alternative get url, back (), navigate command all are failing. my test juz stay still until the define timeout, then ends. any1 else facing similar issue?