# URL does not open with WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My code is

```
package mentor.qa.selenium;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class WDDemo1 {

    public static void main( String[] args){
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();         
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    }
}
```

I am using the latest java jar file 2.47.1 and Firefox 41.0.1. It starts Firefox but does not go to the link. How can I solve that?

Comment: Do you have any additional error messages, stacktraces or logs?

Comment: In problems have 5 warnings. Build path specifies execution environment javaSE-1.7. There are no JREs installed in the workspace that are strictly compatible with this environment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium WebDriver.get(url) does not open the URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7347494/selenium-webdriver-geturl-does-not-open-the-url)

Comment: i dont have double profile in firefox. and i don't use poxy

Comment: I am using windows. how i solve this? is latest jar is compatible with firefox 41.0.1? am also using latest jar and latest firefox 41.0.1

Comment: updated my answer. please have a look

Answer (score 0):

Code is working but optimize imports.

I run your code with minuscule edit. It opens google website. Reverify if you have imported both selenium-java and selenium-server-standalone jar files in the build path.

```
package com.jayant.selenium;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class SampleSelenium {
    public static void main( String[] args){
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code is perfect. It might be configuration issue i.e. use lower version of firefox with same code. It will work

Comment: Did you try it in a lower version or is it just a guess?

Comment: i used the same code in Mozilla Firefox 38.0 , it was working fine

Comment: it's a eclipse issue as I mentioned in my answer