# Selenium doesn't open the specified URL and shows data:,

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to open the URL using selenium in chrome. I have chromedriver available with me.

following is the code I want to execute.

```
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="./chromedriver", chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://google.com")
```

The browser is opened successfully but it doesn't open the specified URL. The URL in the browser is `data:,`.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Please!

Please see the attached image.

Note: Selenium version : 3.14.0

[image]

I get the following error on closing the chrome tab.

```
File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="./chromedriver", chrome_options=chrome_options)
  File "/home/speedious/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 75, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/home/speedious/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 156, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/home/speedious/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 251, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/home/speedious/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 320, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/speedious/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally
  (chrome not reachable)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.42.591071 (0b695ff80972cc1a65a5cd643186d2ae582cd4ac),platform=Linux 4.10.0-37-generic x86_64)
```

Comment: did you mean [driver.get('https://google.com')]

Comment: yes. https://www.google.com

Comment: @Infern0 , Note that specifying scheme (e.g. `http`) is mandatory in Selenium

Comment: its in the comment :P but stackoverflow editor formatted it :P p.s. @monusuri try with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7347494/selenium-webdriver-geturl-does-not-open-the-url

Comment: I'm not using Firefox driver neither a proxy

Comment: @monusuri , make sure you're using [last  chromedriver version](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.42/) along with last  Chrome version

Comment: @Andersson I am using the latest Chrome version

Comment: @monusuri Update the question with the error stack trace and your binary version information

Comment: @DebanjanB There is no error stack trace. The only problem is that it doesn't open the specified URL. But once I close the tab I get the error.

Comment: @monusuri Factually, each and every webdriver variant will produce stack trace while starting which will be the key to address your issue.

Comment: @DebanjanB I have added the error

Comment: from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.google.com/')..this works for me

Comment: @SarthakNegi I have already tried that. That gives me a PATH error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally
  (chrome not reachable)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** instance was unable to start the *Chrome Browser* process.

Your main issue is the **google-chrome** is no longer present at the expected default location of **/usr/bin/**

As per [ChromeDriver - Requirements](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver#requirements) the server expects you to have Chrome installed in the default location for each system:

[image: Chrome_binary_expected_location]

<sup>1</sup> For Linux systems, the ChromeDriver expects /usr/bin/google-chrome to be a symlink to the actual Chrome binary. You can also override the Chrome binary location as follows:

- A Windows OS based example:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

  options = Options()
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.binary_location("C:\\path\\to\\chrome.exe")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)
  driver.get('http://google.com/')
  ```

### Additional Considerations

- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [**ChromeDriver v2.42**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version between ***Chrome v68-70*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.42 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.42/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Execute your `@Test`.

Comment: I have a file called google-chrome in /usr/bin. Do I have to modify it?

Comment: Check the version, possibly an corrupted/older/outdated one. If so uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of Web Client.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still having problems, here is what worked for me.
The problem is that chromium gets installed with snap.
So `which chromium-browser` terminal command outputs nothing. Nothing is installed at `/usr/bin/chromium-browser`.

I tried installing it through `sudo apt install chromium-browser` but that didn't fix it.

**The solution**:

- selenium has a link, where you can download the whole Chrome. [LINK](https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/)

You can then extract this somewhere (for me, it was next to the python script).
So my dir now looked like:

- script.py
- chromedriver_121_0_6167_85
- chrome-linux64

In you script, you now set the path to the chrome binary - `/your/path/to/chrome-linux64/chrome`.
And this fixed it for me.

Here is my script:

```py
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

# Path to Chromium bin
chromium_path = "./chrome-linux64/chrome"  # Replace with the actual path

# Set up Chrome options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.binary_location = chromium_path

url = "https://example.com"
s = Service("./chromedriver_121_0_6167_85")

# Pass the options to the WebDriver
with webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=chrome_options) as driver:
    driver.get(url)
    print("Sleeping for 5 seconds...")
    time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another reason for this behavior, which I don't see listed here. I believe Selenium libraries require Chrome Developer Tools to not be disabled. I was running into this issue and getting this regkey set got me past it.

Key - HKLM\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome

DWORD - DeveloperToolsDisabled

Value - 0