# Address bar shows data:, while trying to scrape using ChromeDriver Chrome through Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, screen-scraping

I am making a simple scraping program.

First, the user will write the name of a `footballer`, then I will make a link to `transfermarkt.com` web search, and then I would like to enter the first link and **scrape** data from the footballer's profile.
Unfortunately, I have a problem with selenium. How do I enter a website programmatically and **scrape** data from the site?

Here is my code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

data = input('Enter name: ')
data = data.replace(" ", "+")
print(data)
link = 'https://www.transfermarkt.pl/schnellsuche/ergebnis/schnellsuche?query='
search = link + data + '&x=0&y=0'
print(search)
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.spielprofil_tooltip tooltipstered').click()
name_box = soup.find('h1', attrs={'class': 'dataValue'})
print(name_box)
```

It works only to line `print(search)`, but then I'm lost. Browser is open, but there is only **`data:,`** in the address bar.

Comment: one suggestion, why don't u retrieve the content of a `url` with `requests.get().text` then pass that to `BeautifulSoup` ?this will eliminate the need for selenium. I can whip up a quick solution for you if you like :)

Comment: You dont need to use BeautifulSoup with selenium, also you dont need to use selenium here :) Use selenium when you can't use requests or when you just want to write your code fast.

Comment: You appear to be mixing/confusing multiple different approaches/libraries. I don't know how much we can do for now.

Comment: @Cryptoharf84 Hello, thank you for your response. I heard beautiful soup is better for scraping but i heard i am not able to do rest of job with it, that's why decided to use selenium. If it is possible to do it without selenium i will appreciate your help :)

Comment: @noname Saying that BeautifulSoup is _better_ than Selenium, or vice-versa, would make little sense, since they serve very different purposes, they're not competitors.

Comment: ok, thank you, but am i able to enter website via Beautiful Soup knowing only name of class which contains my href?

Comment: FYI it’s __scrape__ not scrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need that for headless browser:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
#####
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu') 
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver", options=options)
```

But as I said, you dont need to use selenium here. Use selenium when you can't use requests or when you just want to write your code fast.

> Browser is open, but there is only data:, in the
>   address bar.

Because you didn't get the url in browser:

```
browser.get(source)
```

Comment: Thank you for you explanation. Maybe you have idea how to change this line 'driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.spielprofil_tooltip tooltipstered').click()'
 when i will not use selenium?

Comment: Well, I said "or when you just want to write your code fast." because it is a bit more work with requests. You need to find that anchor (link) and get ``href`` attribute of it (via BeautifulSoup). This attribute is the link when you go if you click on this anchor.

Comment: Try to achieve this, if you cant, I can help you.

Comment: I don't know if you mean this: for example it will be "href="/paulo-dybala/profil/spieler/206050"" - But at the beginning, i don't know which player will be searched by user so this href is unknown and i can't use it.

Comment: You can find it via BeautifulSoup by using it's class selector ('.spielprofil_tooltip tooltipstered')

Comment: Ok, so i assume we have now something like that: 'soup.find('h1', attrs={'class': 'spielprofil_tooltip tooltipstered'})' ?

Comment: Yes, something like it.

Comment: Good, thank you :) Maybe you know why i get information 'name soup is not defined'? Should i define something? I tried 'import soup' but it says there is no module soup but i did before 'pip3 install soup' and i imported also other beautifulsoup staff

Comment: Hmm. Did you find your code form internet? You can [see here](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/) how you should use BeautifulSoup.

Comment: i read docs but i still have problem with this app, i tried to use requests.get to enter new website via class name but it does not work

Comment: Okey, so write your problems in order. And I will help you. If you want, you can add your code too. And [let us continue in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207507/myroom)

Comment: Thank you, so now i want to scrap data from website, but i don't know address this website, i know only class name. First i tried to use 'name_box = soup.find('h1', attrs={'class': 'spielprofil_tooltip tooltipstered'})' but i get an error that i should use HTTP client like requests, but i didn't find any solution to use requests with class name, this line: 'name_box = requests.get('h1', attrs={'class': 'spielprofil_tooltip tooltipstered'}) is not working for me, i know request doesn't use attrs, but i don't know how to replace it with working command

Comment: It is better to continue [in a chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207507/myroom), may you join?

Comment: i would like to join but i don't have enough reputation to talk there

Comment: Oh okay :D I don't know why there is a limit for chat. I wrote a code for you and added comments in it. It finds the link address of person. You can find code here: https://gist.github.com/EkremDincel/a2fdaf919a8050f3dac51a2504872afd

Comment: Oh thank you very much! it works very good! :) i will read it carefully. I have also a question, for example a href will not have a class but will be contained for example in h3 which will have class name. What is to change in code? I think changing in line 33 'a' to 'h3' and writing this class name is not enough because it will not work.

Comment: You are welcome :D If you want to find child elements like that, you should have a look at CSS selectors: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors

Comment: Thank you very much again, you help me the most :D i used 'select' method and some line to extract url and it worked :) now i can try to scarp data :D

Comment: How beautiful for you!

Answer (score 0):

Seems you were close. It works only to the line `print(search)` because though you have constructed the desired url as `search` you haven't invoked `get()` passing the url. So you need to pass the url as follows:

- Code Block:

  ```
  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  data = input('Enter name: ')
  data = data.replace(" ", "+")
  print(data)
  link = 'https://www.transfermarkt.pl/schnellsuche/ergebnis/schnellsuche?query='
  search = link + data + '&x=0&y=0'
  print(search)
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get(search)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Enter name: Kylian Mbappé
  Kylian+Mbappé
  https://www.transfermarkt.pl/schnellsuche/ergebnis/schnellsuche?query=Kylian+Mbappé&x=0&y=0
  ```

Now there can be diverse reasons behind seeing the text **data:,** within the address bar. The error stack trace would have helped us to debug the issue in a better way. However, in majority of the cases this error is due to either of the following issues:

- [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) is not installed at the expected default location.
- *Incompatibility* between the version of the binaries you are using.

---

### Reference

You can find a detailed discussion in:

- [Selenium doesn't open the specified URL and shows data:,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52760842/selenium-doesnt-open-the-specified-url-and-shows-data/52761591#52761591)

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) I will remember that, but with your solution this website still appears on my web browser, i just would like it to open in program to do next stuff, i don't want her to be displayed.

Comment: @noname Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't show this footballer profile, it only shows searching results