# Selenium test not loading some specific URLs

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Using selenium through python on AWS Linux server,  when the test start it doesn't load the page, the strange thing is if I try to run a test using a url from google or facebook the test works, I used `curl` and `links` commands to see if I have access from the server and they work so not sure what could be the issue.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is different about those urls?  If they are behind a proxy, this defect might be related.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7347494/selenium-webdriver-geturl-does-not-open-the-url

Comment: @user964503 What error do you see?

Comment: no error is shown @DebanjanB but I'm taking screenshots and seeing that webpage doesn't load , like I said if I try a different site(like google, facebook, etc.) the screenshot is showing the page so doesn't seem a problem with selenium.

Comment: Found the reason of this issue, it seems a bad configuration with chrome and chromedriver,  I installed https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium , it's a docker image that contains all the dependencies that selenium requires and I was able to run successfully the tests for the URLs , I'm just curious why I was able to run tests for specific URLs but not  for the ones I wanted with my selenium/chrome configuration.